# Citation for a processor instruction set?

Tags: citations, computer-science

I am writing a paper where I am talking about the [SSE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) and [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) instruction sets.  For a hardware feature like an instruction set, I am wondering how to figure out what is an appropriate citation to use, or if it should be cited at all?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Cite their manual

The links to the manuals seem to appear at the reference sections of the respective Wikipedia pages.

Answer (score 3):

It depends what you have to say about them.

If you are going to discuss what individual commands do, presumably you can find a specification or standard describing such from one of the companies or standards bodies involved. You should cite that.

If you want to speak more broadly, such as their performance implications, then you should cite the sources for those statements.

Merely mentioning them, giving a brief overview of what they are (assuming it is original), or providing assembly using them likely does not necessitate citations, as it would be common knowledge given those individual contexts.

Answer (score 0):

The appropriate reference is the Intel Processor Manual for the first processor that introduced the instruction set.